# Best way of doing Collection properties as read only

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

Collection properties

```
public List<MapMarker> Markers { get; set; }
public List<UIReport > Reports { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you mean making the setters of the collection private; or make every possible property in the collections readonly?

Comment: By `read only`, do you mean preventing classes from assigning a brand new collection? Or preventing clients from adding/removing items from that collection? or both?

Comment: You could return `IEnumerable<MapMarker>` if you don't want that someone mistakenly adds or removes items.

Comment: Define "Read only" it can mean different things in different contexts. Are you wanting to prevent `myClass.Makers = someVal`, `myClass.Makers.Add(someVal)`, or `myClass.Makers[0].SomeProp = someVal`

Comment: @TimSchmelter returning IEnumerable does not prevent someone from detecting the underlying type and casting it back to a list.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant if the user decides to break the contract exposed by the class there is nothing you can really do to prevent them.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant: no, but it might be sufficient for OP. I don't know if it is because i don't know what he's actually trying to do or to prevent. That's why i've just commented it.

Comment: True. The request for a "best way" is also subject to opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevents clients from assigning a brand new collection, use a private field (`readonly` if applicable) and a public get-only property.

```
private readonly IList<T> _items = new List<T>();
public IList<T> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
}
```

To prevent clients from assigning a brand new collection *and* modifying your collection, use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`

```
public MyClass()
{
    List<T> list = //new list
    _items = new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(list);    
}

private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<T> _items;
public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
}
```

Returning a list as an `IEnumerable<T>` is not a very reliable option. The client can simply downcast the enumerable back to a list, and mutate. You should wrap the mutable list in a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a readonly collection use the [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

```
var coll = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>("myreadonlycollection".ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public List<MapMarker> Markers { get; private set; }
public List<UIReport > Reports { get; private set; }
```